# How important is the ratio of negative eigenvalues to the convexity of the optimization objective?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have to minimize $f(x)$ with the Hessian matrix $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.
Considering $H$ has one positive eigenvalue with the value of $10^5$ and the rest are equal to $-1$.
In that case, can I rely on a gradient descent optimizer to obtain a global minimum for $f(x)$?

Or let's say "what can we say about the convergence point of the convex solver?" 
Can I claim the convergence point would be really close to the global optimum?

Comment: is $\nabla^{2} f(x)=H$ constant?  In that case, your problem is simply unbounded!

Comment: You do appreciate, I hope, that this is not a convex function!